# Using attribute filter on Enum fields -C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if anyone could help me out here.  I have a large flagged enum that is used with setting application permissions.  The thing is, I want to limit who can see what based on their permissions within the application.  I was wondering if this could easily be done with an attribute filter.  I'm familiar with action filters and their usefulness, but not with other filters that could potentially do this.  I would like to limit the level of access that the user can see to their level and lower.  The first part are the permissions and the second part is the level of access to the application.

An example of what i would like to do is:

Person A has the mc_pm role, so they can see everything.

Person B has the bn_pm role, so they should only be able to see "battalion, company, and section" for the level of access.

Here's the enum in question.

```
[Flags]
public enum Permissions : int
{
    disabled = 0,
    leadership = 1 << 1,
    personnelManagement = 1 << 2,
    sectionPoc = 1 << 3,
    siteAdministrator = 1 << 4,
    supervisor = 1 << 5,
    user = 1 << 6,
    userAdministrator = 1 << 7,

    majorCommand = 1 << 8,
    brigade = 1 << 9,
    battalion = 1 << 10,
    company = 1 << 11,
    division = 1 << 12,
    section = 1 << 13,

    mc_leadership = majorCommand | leadership,
    mc_pm = majorCommand | personnelManagement,
    mc_ua = majorCommand | userAdministrator,
    mc_su = majorCommand | supervisor,

    bd_leadership = brigade | leadership,
    bd_pm = brigade | personnelManagement,
    bd_su = brigade | supervisor,
    bd_ua = brigade | userAdministrator,

    bn_leadership = battalion | leadership,
    bn_pm = battalion | personnelManagement,
    bn_su = battalion | supervisor,
    bn_ua = battalion | userAdministrator,

    co_leadership = company | leadership,
    co_pm = company | personnelManagement,
    co_su = company | supervisor,
    co_ua = company | userAdministrator,

    s_leadership = section | leadership,
    s_pm = section | personnelManagement,
    s_su = section | supervisor
}
```

Example of how i would like to proceed:

```
    [AllowRoles(mc_pm,mc_ua)]
    majorCommand = 1 << 8,
    [AllowRoles(mc_pm,mc_ua,bd_pm,bd_ua)]
    brigade = 1 << 9,
    [AllowRoles(mc_pm,mc_ua,bd_pm,bd_ua,cn_pm,bn_ua)]
    battalion = 1 << 10,
    [AllowRoles(mc_pm,mc_ua,bd_pm,bd_ua,bn_pm,bn_ua,co_pm,co_ua)]
    company = 1 << 11,
    [AllowRoles(mc_pm,mc_ua,bd_pm,bd_ua,bn_pm,bn_ua,co_pm,co_ua)]
    division = 1 << 12,
    [AllowRoles(mc_pm,mc_ua,bd_pm,bd_ua,bn_pm,bn_ua,co_pm,co_ua)]
    section = 1 << 13,
```

Now, I know i can just separate out the enums, but if it isn't necessary, then that would be better.

**edit:** The enum above will be used to make a multi-select list for the front-end user administrators to be able to grant specific permission levels. the 0-7 bit shifted elements are the permissions and the 8-13 bit shifted items are the level of access granted to each permission.

Comment: "I want to limit who can see what based on their permissions." In this context, what do you mean by "see" ? Are we talking about a user interface that presents these as options somehow? Or are we talking about constraints to be applied to a field in API calls?

Comment: This enum will be used to make a multi-select list for the user administrators to select effective site permissions.

Comment: Regardless of whether you _can_ do what you propose, I'll argue whether you _should_.  It's easier to use and maintain the code if you separate the enums (the S in SOLID).  What happens when you want to add another level of permissions (to the 0-7 group)?  How easy would it be to make that change in this 'all-in-one-enum' scheme?

Comment: Sean, perhaps you are right. I was looking at just storing everything in one field in the database. Perhaps i should just stick to two fields.  That being said, i'll have to use both conditions to filter and sort what users can see in the database.  That would be much simpler if i could use the combined flags instead.